# Access specific child class functions whose objects are in a template class vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector, subclass, multiple-inheritance

I'm new here and I hope you can help me! :)

My problem is the following:

First, I have this class diagram:

[diagram](http://up.picr.de/22078239pr.jpg)

Additionally, I have another class `Rocket` which has a `vector` that should contain all the rocket-parts as pointers that I generate.
My problem is that the `Rocket` class contains 3 calculation methods, for example:

```
template<typename T>
double Rocket<T>::calcTWR(){
    double thrust = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_parts.size();i++){
        thrust += m_parts[i]->getThrust();
    }
    return thrust;
}
```

Yes, I used a template because I wasn't entirely sure how to handle all those sub classes and I thought a template might be fitting here. Plus, and that's where the problem arises, it doesn't seem to work that the call `rocket.calcTWR();` can handle it: Compiler says that

> getThrust() is not a member of 'RocketPart'

I understand that much but how to solve it? How do I declare a vector within `Rocket` that is able to contain all subclasses of `RocketPart` and in the `main` how do I call `calcTWR()`, so that it actually gives back the total `thrust`, regardless of the contents of the `vector`?

Please keep it simple, I'm still a beginner! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `m_parts` is a vector of pointers to the common base class?

Then you need to [*downcast*](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php#Downcasting) to the correct class, like

```
static_cast<ActualClassThisIs*>(m_parts[i])->getThrust();
```

Note that this only works if the class inherits from the base class. Also note that it will not work if the actual class *isn't* what you cast it to. Then you might have to use `dynamic_cast` and check for `nullptr`:

```
if (dynamic_cast<ActualClassThisIs*>(m_parts[i]) != nullptr)
    dynamic_cast<ActualClassThisIs*>(m_parts[i])->getThrust();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last part,

> How do I declare a vector within Rocket that is able to contain all subclasses of RocketPart and in the main how do I call calcTWR(), so that it actually gives back the total thrust, regardless of the contents of the vector?

Could be done with something along these lines:

```
class IPart {
    virtual double getThrust() = 0;
}
class MetalPart : public IPart {
    double getThrust() override { return 5.5; }
}
class PlasticPart : public IPart {
    double getThrust() override { return 3.3; }
}
class CrappyPart : public IPart {
    double getThrust() override { return 1.1; }
}
```

and then you keep them in a

```
std::vector<IPart*> parts;
```

And can then calculate the total thrust with something like this:

```
double total = 0;
for(auto part : parts) {
    total += part->getThrust();
}
```

Sorry, your diagram wasn't readable on my screen so I made some names up.